attempt to index ? (a nil value) with key 'start' (field '2') in game guardian script
I want to make a script and an error like this appears, can anyone help?
Tester=gg.getRangesList('libil2cpp.so')[2].start`



attempt to index ? (a nil value) with key 'start' (field '2')



level = 1, const = 30, proto = 0, upval = 1, vars = 4, code = 79



GETTABLE v0 v0 "start"



 ; PC 36 CODE 00434007 OP 7 A 0 B 0 C 269 Bx 269 sBx -130802

My script:
function money1()

gg.setVisible(false)

gg.alert ("CLICK LEVEL 3 THEN CLICK ON THE GG LOGO TO START")

gg.clearResults()

gg.clearList()

while true do

if gg.isVisible() then

break

else

gg.sleep(50)

end end gg.setVisible(false) gg.clearResults()

Tester=gg.getRangesList('libil2cpp.so')[2].start

Lua=0x5D28E08 setvalue(Tester+Lua,16,1917191729192019001910)

gg.setRanges(32)

gg.searchNumber("40", 16)

gg.getResults(9999)

gg.editAll("50000000", 16)

gg.alert ("CLICK LEVEL 1")

gg.toast("ON")

gg.clearResults()

gg.clearList()

end

Game guardian & Lua script.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This is the most common error in Lua. You are attempting to index a nil value which doesn't make sense and hence is not allowed so it results in an error message.
gg.getRangesList('libil2cpp.so')[2] is nil. The table returned by gg.getRangesList('libil2cpp.so') does not contain a value at index 2.
I don't know why you expect a value there or if there should be one in the first place. Find out why it is nil and fix it or don't index it if it is not indexable.
This should be obvious if you would have read the first view pages of the Lua manual.
https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.1
